# "npm test" not showing test results in the vs code terminal

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

When I run "npm test", vs code doesn't show the test results. Instead I get this in my terminal.

```
PS C:\Users\Rabten\Desktop\random> npm test

> test
> jest
```

I am trying to test a simple functions that creates a node using a factory functions. Below are the js file and the test file.

node.js

```
function Node(data) {
 let value = data || null;
 let next = null;

 return {
   value,
   next,
  };
} 
module.exports = Node;
```

And the test file.

```
const Node = require('./node');

test('does Node create a new node with correct value ?', () => {
let newNode = Node('Rabten');

expect(newNode).toEqual({value: "Rabten", next: null})
});
```

So any helps will be appreciated. I am not sure whether it is a vs code settings problems or something else.

And also when I run "npm test", vs code automatically opens the node.js file if I am in node.test.js file.

Below is my package.json.

```
{"devDependencies": {"jest": "^29.5.0"},"scripts": {"test": "jest"}}
```

And my folder structure.

```
>node_modules
node.js
node.test.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

Comment: Can you install JestJS VScode extension and use that?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to show terminal output and code as text, please, not images. Also add your `package.json` since you have no `jest.config.js`

Comment: JestJS is in the extension marketplace in vs code ??

Comment: Yes https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firsttris.vscode-jest-runner

Comment: I am still getting the same result.

Comment: 1) That extension is to be used from the Run tab, not the terminal 2) Does not render output in the default terminal , rather "Output" tab 3) Please edit post again to show both your JS files as text

Comment: Can you please tell me what the run tab is ??

Comment: Sorry, above link was wrong. Meant this one. See the images https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest

Comment: Can you please tell me what a "run tab" is ?? I am still stuck !!!

Comment: I never said "run tab". I said `OUTPUT`. Look at the images in the above docs for the "Test Explorer" panel

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing us your project folder structure or file names.
Still, my guess is the default test match patterns doesn't find your test.

Put the test in `__tests__` folder or name it `*.test.js` or `*.spec.js`

Comment: The folder structure is very simple. All in the same levels. I will edit my original question and show it there. I think the problem was I didn't use "npm init". It has been working since I created a package.json file before intsalling jest.

Comment: Ah, so you didn't have a project with package.json. Did you install jest globally instead?

Comment: yes, I installed it globally.